# Drawing a curve / radius on a oval radius shape in Sketchup

Tags: sketchup

I'm trying to achieve what the image shows.

The 4 corners need to be rounded.

How to do this on a flat surface and on a surface already drawn like the attached, specially.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a few options:

1. Use solid operations (booleans)
2. Draw each segment connecting to each other individually
3. Draw the whole thing flat, with the rounded corners, then get hold of and use the TrueBend extension and bend your resulting geometry.